# How to disable builtin email app

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, stock-email-app

On my new tablet I installed the gmail app and also configured the builtin app. Now I get two notifications for each email. How can I get rid of the builtin email app which does not seem as good as the gmail app?

Comment: If you have root access, you can use an application like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) which is capable of removing system level applications.

Comment: Ok. If you don't have root what should you do to sensibly use the gmail app without this duplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have root you can do as suggested and use Titanium Backup to remove the stock email app.

If you aren't rooted you can remove the duplicate notification by going into the stock email app, settings, and then delete your email account from the app.

If you want to keep your account you can also go into your phone settings and find the application manager, swipe over to the all apps tab, find the stock email app and uncheck show notifications (if your android version is jelly bean).

Comment: In 5.0 you can also directly "deactivate" the app via application manager after deleting all mail accounts associated with it via android settings > accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Connect device via ADB
2. Go to ADB shell

   ```
   adb shell
   ```
3. Remove app like this

   ```
   pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.email
   ```